# Unable to protect pages/area with password

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I'm trying to create a password protected area of a website.
I'd like to allow access by checking username and password from a MySql table, then start a session and allow access to a number of pages while the session is active. If someone tries to directly access one of these pages directly, I'd like to redirect them to login page.

My code for the login page is:

```
     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {     
    include("config.php");
    session_start();
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $passwordc=md5($password);        

    $query = "SELECT username FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$passwordc'";
     $result2 = $conn->query($query);

    if ($result2->num_rows != 0) {          

    $_SESSION["username"] = $user;
      echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> location.href='admin_view.php' </script>";   
    }else{
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('User Name Or Password Invalid!')</script>";
    }

    }
```

It seems to work (correctly redirects if username and password matches, shows alert if not).
What I fail to do, is actually protect my pages from display if session is not active.

```
   session_start();
if (!$_SESSION["username"]) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

I'm not a programmer or fully-educated web developer. I know HTML and CSS, and I'm barely able to use ready-to-use php and js scripts following readme files.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MD5 is not good enough. Use build in `passwird_hash`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements

Comment: The page I want to protect with password displays even if directly accessed (without passing through the login page first)

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @Dharman: thanks, but atm security is not my main issue. Once I will be able to actually block pages if users not logged in, I'll work on improving security.

Comment: Try `if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks, but as said, my problem now id that I cannot understand how to check if session is active and display or block the pages I want to protect.

I mean, my login+session script doesn't work at all, so improving security at the moment is pointless

Comment: Also you dont actually say, but is that SESSION checking code part of ALL the pages you want to protect? i.e. Did you include that code on all the pages you want protecting

Comment: @RiggsFolly

>>Try if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {

Thanks! 
Tried it, but still the page reacts as if the session is not active (redirects).

Comment: Actually, I have firts code (in main post) in the login page, second code snipped at the top of pagesI want to protect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your login code as

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {     
   include("config.php");
  $username= $crud->escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $password= $crud->escape_string($_POST['password']);
   $passwordc=md5($password); 
   $query = "SELECT username FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND 
   password='$passwordc'";
   $result2 = $conn->query($query);
  if ($result2->num_rows != 0) { 
   session_start();         
  $_SESSION["username"] = $user;
  header("Location:admin_view.php");   
}else{
  $Message = urlencode("user name password invalid!");
                      header("Location:login.php?Message=".$Message);
}
   }
```

if your values successfully stored in session then you can use like

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
  {
  header("Location: login.php");  
  }
```

on everypage top
you must store name from query into session

Comment: Always exit after header, don't use MD5 for hashing, and use prepared statements.

Comment: Thank youvery much!